# vim can not delete Chinese character on mac os

Tags: vim, macos-sierra

vim compiled by homebrew can not delete Chinese character on insert-mode,but it can delete USA character;And after uninstalled the homebrew-compiled vim,and use the vim pre-installed of mac,it can work all well.

the homebrew installed vim version:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Aug 22 2018 13:55:00)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-300
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +tag_old_static
+arabic            +farsi             +mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white
+autocmd           +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tcl
+autochdir         +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       +termguicolors
-autoservername    +float             +mouse_xterm       +terminal
-balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term -footer            +multi_lang        +termresponse
-browse            +fork()            -mzscheme          +textobjects
++builtin_terms    -gettext           +netbeans_intg     +timers
+byte_offset       -hangul_input      +num64             +title
+channel           +iconv             +packages          -toolbar
+cindent           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +user_commands
-clientserver      +job               +perl              +vartabs
+clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +visual
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +visualextra
+comments          +libcall           -python            +viminfo
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3           +vreplace
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +wildignore
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +wildmenu
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +windows
+cursorshape       -lua               +ruby              +writebackup
+dialog_con        +menu              +scrollbind        -X11
+diff              +mksession         +signs             -xfontset
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       -xim
-dnd               +mouse             +startuptime       -xpm
-ebcdic            -mouseshape        +statusline        -xsmp
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+eval              -mouse_gpm         +syntax            -xterm_save
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X -DMACOS_X_DARWIN  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: clang   -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib  -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lncurses -liconv -framework AppKit   -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/5.28.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -lm -lutil -lc  -L/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-darwin -lpython3.7m -framework CoreFoundation  -lruby.2.5.1 -lobjc
```

the mac pre-installed vim version:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Nov 29 2017 18:37:46)
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
...
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lm -lncurses  -liconv -framework Cocoa
```

what's wrong here?

Comment: can you show the `...` compilation options, those (+) and (-) ? Particularly the first (not working) one

Comment: i added it @Kent

Comment: you have already `+multi_byte`, it should work.. what do you mean you cannot delete under insert mode, what happens if you pressed DEL/BSpace?

Comment: @Kent the cursor just not moving when i pressed DEL;but after i pressed some USA character,and press DEL,it can delete USA character util to the Chinese charater.

Comment: Does it really depend on what the previous character is? Or does it depend on which mode your IME is in? (Those two are usually parallel - if you wrote a Chinese character last, you're probably in Chinese IME, and if you wrote a Latin character last, you're probably in non-Chinese input mode; but I am very interested to know which one of those correlated things is the real problem)

Comment: @Amadan I try it on Chinese and non-Chinese IME，but it only can delete Latin charater.The Chinese character can not delete on both of all.

Comment: @ixiaohei when you were trying with two vims, were you using same vimrc?

Comment: @Kent yes，but i am not using them in same time.

Comment: @Amadan I know the way to solve the problem. When i create `.vimrc` file, the backspace is vi mode(set backspace=).Add `set backspace=indent,eol,start` solved it.